# Mysql Select 5 rows where sum of one combined column best matches a determined value

Tags: php, mysql, sum

First, I have not even started coding this query yet simply because I don't know how to approach it. The scenario is this. In table_name I need to query against column_a selecting (all columns in) the rows that best sum up to a determined value. My value for this example could be 150. results in column_a could be (3,25,67,19,9,11) etc. I need the five rows that when added together will be closest to 150. In this case the query would give me rows (67,25,19,11,9).

```
SELECT * FROM 5 rows -> WHERE SUM(column_a) closest matches 150
```

this example is close to what I am looking for except I need the total and the rows resulting.
[Sum top 5 values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294003/sum-top-5-values-in-mysql)

I hope i have explained this well enough. I have a feeling this will be a simple problem I've just simply way over thought.

Thanks

Comment: give some data and wished result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a table t with one column val

```
select * from t as t1, t as t2, t as t3, t as t4, t as t5
order by abs(t1.val + t2.val + t3.val + t4.val + t5.val - 150)
limit 1
```

Note that this will be a slow query.

Comment: I think this might do it, I'll check it when I get home. As far as speed I would like to have it fast of course, but, on the same note the table in question will be no more than 200 rows max anyway.Thanks

Comment: I made some changes of course to fit my needs, but, this pointed me in the right direction.