# Understand the behavior of a query using user variables

Tags: mysql, subquery

I was looking for a query that sums the top n values for each user. Fortunately, I found the solution in this post [Sum top 5 values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294003/sum-top-5-values-in-mysql)
However, I'm having a harsh time understanding the given solution which is :

```
SELECT driver, SUM(`position`)
FROM (SELECT driver, race, season, `position`, 
         IF(@lastDriver=(@lastDriver:=driver), @auto:=@auto+1, @auto:=1) indx 
  FROM results, (SELECT @lastDriver:=0, @auto:=1) A 
  ORDER BY driver, `position`) AS A  
WHERE indx <= 5 
GROUP BY driver ;
```

Can someone explain how it works especially the subquery after the FROM Clause ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: :-) you are having a harsh time? not just a hard time? +1 hugs for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL @variables are like doing an inline program of setting a variable, comparing and then using the result as basis for next row being compared...  Let me re-format your query for a little better following / readability.

```
SELECT 
      driver, 
      SUM(`position`)
   FROM 
      ( SELECT 
              driver, 
              race, 
              season, 
              `position`, 
              IF( @lastDriver = ( @lastDriver := driver), 
                  @auto := @auto + 1, 
                  @auto := 1) indx 
        FROM 
           results, 
           (SELECT @lastDriver := 0, 
                   @auto := 1) A 
        ORDER BY 
           driver, 
           `position`) AS A  
   WHERE 
      indx <= 5 
   GROUP BY 
      driver ;
```

The inner "From" clause starts the query.  The Select @ is like you having a program that does..

```
set @auto = 1
set @lastDriver = 0
```

to prepare the variables.

Because you have an order by clause the query will grab records from the "results" table and put them in order.  This is like a queue of records ABOUT to be processed.  Now, think of the query running all the records through a do/while loop.  Remember, your @auto = 1 and @lastDriver = 0 to start.

Now, the query will process the records in order, and as it goes ONE FIELD AT A TIME is like the query saying...

```
Add the driver to the result
add the race to the result
add the season to the result
add the `position` to the result
```

Now for what you are probably waiting for... what is going on with the IF() and @ variables.  The IF() is like the following

```
IF( some condition )
   add this value to the result
else
   add this value to the result
```

In this case, the @lastDriver = ( @lastDriver := driver ) is pseudo something like..

```
set HoldLastDriver = @lastDriver
set @lastDriver = the driver of the current record being processed
if( HoldLastDriver = new value of @lastDriver -- current record driver )
   set the auto value = auto value +1
else
   set the auto value back to 1 because the driver just changed
```

The result of this is put into the "indx" column.

So, now, when it gets to the next row, the @lastDriver and @auto have been updated and continue from there... So, if you have the following data, the list will show what the values might be of just showing the driver and auto columns as this is the basis of the as that is the critical element for the query.

```
                        BEFORE ROW PROCESSED  AFTER ROW PROCESSED
driver pos/race/season  @lastDriver @auto     @lastDriver @auto
  1     3 / A / A           0        1           1        1
  1     3 / B / A           1        1           1        2
  1     4 / D / B           1        2           1        3
  1     5 / E / D           1        3           1        4
  1     7 / F / D           1        4           1        5
  1     7 / G / D           1        5           1        6
  2     2 / A / A           1        6           2        1
  2     2 / B / A           2        1           2        2
  3     1 / A / A           2        2           3        1
  3     2 / B / A           3        1           3        2
  3     2 / D / B           3        2           3        3
  3     2 / E / D           3        3           3        4
  3     3 / F / D           3        4           3        5
  3     3 / G / D           3        5           3        6
```

To end the query, now that all these records are processed, your outer query will process the driver and sum() but only for the records where "indx" (the AFTER version of @auto) is less or equal to 5... so the two records where @auto was 6 (driver 1 & 3) would NOT be considered in the result summation.